# Why I'm getting an error while creating a new model class in django?

Tags: python, django, model

I have read similar questions but couldn't come to a solution or a conclusion about it. I got this error while creating a new model class in the same app as well as creating a new model class in a new app. The error

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_permission.content_type_id, auth_permission.codename
```

my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

CHOICES = (('Earned Leave','Earned Leave'),('Casual Leave','Casual Leave'),('Sick Leave','Sick Leave'),('Paid Leave','Paid Leave'))
STATUS_CHOICES = (('0', 'Rejected'),('1', 'Accepted'),)
MANAGER_CHOICES = (('0001_manager', '0001_manager'),('0002_manager', '0002_manager'))

class Leave(models.Model):

    employee_ID = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null =True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class B(models.Model):

    state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Comment: Looks not related, there is a problem with the authentication app. Probably if you remove the model, the problem will still persist.

Comment: Is it possible that you *manually* populated the database with permissions?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem once I delete the `class B(models.Model):` and the file from the migrations folder and re-migrate then it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete all your previous migrations and again migrate, make-migrations. It'll work.